# Average Time Complexity

Tags: python, recursion, time, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have a recursive function as you can see from below. I also have the iterative version of same function. My problem is about recursive function's time complexity. Based on my knowledge it should be O(n^2). What is the time complexity of this function? If it is O(n^2);
I test two functions(iterative-recursive) with same input why is there a huge difference between running times? Thank you

Time Difference For Iterative :4.045395
Time Difference For Recursive :20.554156

```
def naive_dac(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return 0

    count = naive_dac(list(arr[0:len(arr) - 1]))
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        if int(arr[i]) > int(arr[len(arr) - 1]):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Iterative version

```
def brute_force(arr):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        for j in range(i,len(arr)):
            if arr[j] < arr[i]:
                count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Please show your iterative version too.

Comment: @rendon I added iterative function

Comment: Have you seen if `count += sum( arr[i]>arr[i:]  )` improves the speed, assuming that `arr` is a NumPy array, and doing a function comprehension for the outer `i` rather than putting that in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the recursive version but I think the problem is this line:

```
count = naive_dac(list(arr[0:len(arr) - 1]))
```

Every time you call the recursive function you are creating a copy of your list and this operation is time consuming. Depending on the size of the list this can affect drastically the algorithm's performance. Is really necessary to create a copy?

Assuming that your algorithm is correct and as you don't modify the list you can use a variable to store the length of the list.

```
def naive_dac(arr, length):
    if length == 1:
        return 0

    count = naive_dac(arr, length - 1)
    for i in range(0, length):
        if arr[i] > arr[length-1]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

**EDIT**: The extra overhead was caused by the castings: `int(arr[i]) ...`.

Comment: Actually no. I just need to count inversions. Is that the reason about time difference?

Comment: It's a possible reason. What is the size of your list?

Comment: Size of the list is 10.000

Comment: OMG. I'm now 99% sure.

Comment: The problem was list function creates a new array right. That is why my function did really bad about space complexity

Comment: I changed my code with your suggestion but difference is still too much. It is 17 now. Can I send kind of address for arr in python?

Comment: I have a bug in my proposed solution. Wait a minute.

Comment: that is what exactly tried actually. I already did that changes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46296/discussion-between-rendon-and-gungor-basa)